# how do I remove svg tag/node from file in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, xml, svg

Hello guys i generate in NodeJs QR picture with qrcode library and try to remove <?xml ...> tag from svg file,

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">`

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 33 33" shape-rendering="crispEdges"><path fill="#ffffff" d="M0 0h33v33H0z"/><path stroke="#000000" d="M4 4.5h7m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m3 0h7M4 5.5h1m5 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h1m5 0h1M4 6.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h3m2 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1M4 7.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h3m3 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1M4 8.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1m3 0h1m1 0h3m1 0h1M4 9.5h1m5 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h1m2 0h1m3 0h1m5 0h1M4 10.5h7m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h7M13 11.5h2m3 0h3M4 12.5h1m1 0h1m3 0h2m2 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h1m2 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1M4 13.5h1m1 0h3m5 0h2m1 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h1m1 0h2M6 14.5h1m2 0h2m2 0h2m1 0h1m2 0h1m4 0h3m1 0h1M5 15.5h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m3 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h3m1 0h2M4 16.5h1m1 0h1m3 0h1m1 0h2m2 0h2m1 0h2m1 0h1m5 0h1M8 17.5h2m1 0h3m2 0h1m2 0h5m3 0h2M4 18.5h2m3 0h2m2 0h1m2 0h5m1 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h1M6 19.5h1m1 0h2m2 0h2m1 0h2m1 0h2m1 0h1m1 0h3M4 20.5h2m2 0h1m1 0h1m3 0h1m2 0h8m2 0h1M12 21.5h3m2 0h2m1 0h1m3 0h1m3 0h1M4 22.5h7m1 0h1m2 0h1m4 0h1m1 0h1m1 0h1m3 0h1M4 23.5h1m5 0h1m2 0h2m2 0h1m1 0h2m3 0h1m2 0h2M4 24.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m3 0h4m1 0h6m2 0h2M4 25.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m5 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h1m1 0h2M4 26.5h1m1 0h3m1 0h1m1 0h1m3 0h3m1 0h1m2 0h3m1 0h2M4 27.5h1m5 0h1m2 0h4m1 0h4m1 0h2M4 28.5h7m1 0h1m1 0h1m2 0h2m1 0h3m2 0h1m2 0h1"/></svg>`

somebody recomend me to use fast-xml-parser but after parsing file svg code is broken

1. may in qrcode library when generate svg file some option to exclude <?xml ...> ?
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode
2. with fast-xml-parser how possible to not broke svg data ? https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser

3 may some better library solution ?

thanks for help

Comment: because i save in json file and render in react => return(<svg>{svgFromJson}</svg>)

Comment: I can extract data with powershell.  SVG files can be huge and give memory exceptions.  Most libraries do not work with huge xml files, but XmlReader will work.

Comment: According to [the documentation for the library](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/master/docs/v4/2.XMLparseOptions.md) you mention in your question you just set ignoreDeclaration: true

Comment: https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser/blob/master/docs/v4/2.XMLparseOptions.md#ignoredeclaration